# What is Sigma over x?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, notation

What does $\sum_xx$ mean?

I'm used to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$, but what's the above?

**Update**: I find in our statistics book these notations:

$$\sum_{x}|x-\tilde{a}|f(x)$$

Comment: Look up sigma notation. The former is used if there isn't a lot of printing space.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $X$ once and $x$ once?

Comment: @Holo, yes I am

Comment: where do you see the notation?

Comment: If $x$ naturally ranges over a set of possible values -- e.g. $x$ is always used to refer to the elements of a finite set $X$ -- then I would interpret this to mean the sum of all the values which $x$ can reasonably take. But more context is necessary to say anything with certainty.

Comment: The $x$ ranges over all values in some implicit set.

Comment: The expression $\sum_{x}|x-\bar{x}|f(x)$ is the mean absolute deviation about the mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The summation notation varies a lot but from what I can tell, the one you're showing us is simply a contraction, mainly: $$\sum_x x = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x$$ that has meaning if $x\in\mathbb{N}$. But if $x$ is in some sort of set, like $x\in X$ surely the notation is used as a contraction for $$\sum_{x\in X}x = \sum_x x$$ like, for example, if $X = \left\{10,22,35,55.5,\pi\right\}$ the sum should be $$\sum_x x = 10+22+35+55.5+\pi$$ so the sum on all the possible value that $x$ can have

### Edit

By telling us where you found that notation is clear that **yes** we are summing over a set of possible value for $x$. I'm not a statistician but from what I recall $$Var[x] = \sum_x (x-\bar{x})^2f(x)$$ so you have a certain set of measurement, for example, and this measurement follows a certain PDF $f(x)$. To calculate the variance you sum over all the measured value of $x$ in your statistical set according to that formula

Comment: Yes it is. In the book it's defined as $$s_{x}^{2}=\frac{\sum_x(x-\bar{x})^2f(x)}{n}$$.